# Call a static block in jquery lightbox in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, lightbox, block

I want to call static block in jquery lightbox. I am showing a lightbox on hamoe page automatically after some seconds. I want to call a static block in that light box so that admin can be able to change content of lightbox by changing the static block using editor.

So far I have done this

```
<a id="pop" href="{{block type=”cms/block” block_id=”social”}}"></a>
```

And called it in jquery fancybox. But it shows a 404 page in lightbox and social block embedded in that!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new page and set **layout empty** from **design tab**.

Once you have page, just call it in fancy box like this.

```
<a href='<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(). you_page_identifie?>' class='fancybox'><?php echo $this->__('Fancy box content from admin cms') ?></a>
```